# All of folders in /etc are readonly in centos

Tags: centos6

I am trying to run an installer in CentOs,But all of folders in /etc have read-only permission,So I can run anything.All of folders have a lock image beside them.
Beside I am admin and use account root.
What should I do to have correct permissions?

Comment: Contact system admin to grant you sudoer permission over /etc.

Comment: I am admin,I use account root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you wanna change the permissions to read and write for all the Files and Folders within the /etc Folder

run the following code

```
chmod -R 0777 etc
```

additionally you can change ownership of the folder using the chown command i.e

```
chown -R owner:group etc
```

Regards

Comment: Not a good idea that everybody can write to /etc

Comment: thats just an example

Comment: @samantha welcome my friend

Answer (score 0):

Then the installer don't have root access. You must open/start the installer as root. If you are using command line to run this installer you must type `sudo [whatever command you are using]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
chmod -R +w /etc
```

As it gives write access for you to everything under /etc

Comment: It does not work,All of folders are lock :(